# Retrieve decimal numbers from String and put them in an [Int] list recursively

Tags: string, list, haskell, recursion, type-conversion

I am working through learnyouahaskell chapters and have been experimenting with recursive functions (and guards). I found some exercises, one of which where I am to retrieve the decimal numbers from a String in the form of [Int]. This is what I have so far:

```
retrieveDecimalsFromString :: String -> [Int]
retrieveDecimalsFromString (x:xs)
    | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] = x:retrieveDecimalsFromString xs
    | otherwise = retrieveDecimalsFromString xs
```

This crashes, which I understand, because I am returning a String rather than [Int]. I can't seem to find a solution for this though. Maybe my approach is wrong. Alternatively (without recursion) I tried:

```
retrieveDecimalsFromString :: String -> [Int]
retrieveDecimalsFromString xs = filter (`elem` ['0'..'9']) xs
```

Which leads to the same problem. Can above be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When you use recursion, you should have a base condition. In your code, when the string is empty, what will it do? That is your base condition. So, change the function definition like this

   ```
   retrieveDecimalsFromString :: String -> [Int]
   retrieveDecimalsFromString "" = []
   ```

   The base condition says that, if the input is an empty string, I ll return an empty list.
2. Now, when `x` is one of the digits, what will `x:retrieveDecimalsFromString xs` do? It will try to create a list. But the first element, `x` is a `Char` and as per the definition of `retrieveDecimalsFromString`, the return value is `[Int]`. So, you need to convert the `Char` to `Int`, like this

   ```
   retrieveDecimalsFromString (x:xs)
       | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] = (digitToInt x):retrieveDecimalsFromString xs
       | otherwise = retrieveDecimalsFromString xs
   ```

---

In the `filter` version, you are saying `retrieveDecimalsFromString` will return `[Int]` as per the signature, but the result of filtering would be a `[Char]`. That is why it is not working. You can fix that by changing the type in either of the places like this

```
retrieveDecimalsFromString :: String -> [Char]
retrieveDecimalsFromString xs = filter (`elem` ['0'..'9']) xs
```

Or

```
retrieveDecimalsFromString :: String -> [Int]
retrieveDecimalsFromString xs = map digitToInt $ filter (`elem` ['0'..'9']) xs
```

**Note:** [`digitToInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) function is in `Data.Char`. So you need to import it before using it.

Comment: I was struggling with the base condition initially, for the purpose of my question I removed my (incorrect) line. Thanks for clearing this up as well. Your in-depth explanation confirms my own thought process. I did come across digitToInt, but I wasn't aware of the use of imports in Haskell. Thank you so much, it's working like a charm!

Comment: `retrieveDecimalsFromString = map digitToInt . filter isDigit` looks a bit more nice.